# Storing React-Native Components in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to retrieve data from a local JSON file which I want to hold components

```
 "Element1": {
     "key": "1",
     "data": "<MyReactComponent />"
 }
```

Now whenever I try to use Element1.data as a component, it gives me a "Raw Text" error. I understand that it is because Element1.data is a String. Is there a way I can use it as a component? I've tried JSON.parse() but haven't had any luck. Can you only store Strings in JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
import MyReactComponent from './MyReactComponent'

const data = {
 "Element1": {
     "key": "1",
     "component": (props = {}) => <MyReactComponent {...props} />
 }
}
```

You will have to render this component like this:

```
render() {
   return data['Element1'].component({})
}
```

In this way, you can pass some props dynamically.